# Know for which project/issue types a specific behavior is used in Jira data center

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Is there a way to know for which projects/issue types a bahavior is used in Jira? I am thinking of upgrading ScriptRunner and I need to know the exact usage of a specific fragment and its specific domain of application. When I go to fragments, I get the following information which is not that helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Behaviour, if it's used you should be able to see the project and issue type mapping it apply to, If there is nothing it's not bind to any project.